Getting null or empty from an excel cell, cannot difference them fronm the excel
I have developed an application that reads the values from an Excel, and that data will be processed in some way and then stored in a DB.
I have tested it on about 400 different rows, with 63 columns per row dependent on 8 different Excels. All perfect. But the code has been uploaded to production, and the first empty cell, instead of reading an empty, has read a null and an exception has been produced, breaking the flow of the program. What could be the reason (and if it can be changed from Excel) so that empty cells continue to return empty and not null.
I don't know what code to provide you, I don't think it will help you much. To me it seems something related to the Excel format. Even so, here you are, anything you need, please ask me.
var cellAA = sheet.GetRow(i).GetCell(j);


I double check, it is not random. If there is nothing in the cell, it will always be null in c#, but if there is a ="" in the cell, you will still see a blank cell in Excel, but it will be an empty string in c#.

@rachel. Yep, sorry for the confusing title of the question. My problem here is how are you differencing, from the excel, when the cell is empty or null? I cannot get the difference but i want to warn the person who provides the excel in order he can fix it in case is wrong. Besides, I am handling now, both cases, but I want still to defence my code and show to the user the difference between the original excel, empty, to the new one, null. Many thanks for helping here.

Not sure of your question. But in Excel, you can differentiate either by selecting the cell and examining the formula bar, or by applying the formula ISBLANK(cell_ref)

Yes. if it is not null, but an empty string for your original file, then ISBLANK(cell_ref) will return FALSE.

@RonRosenfeld. Strange.... I am receiving TRUE in both case. Well, I want to check a excel before upload it and can detect when the cell will return blank or empty. Is that possible?

@rachel +++. Please, checl the previous comment. Many thanks both.

Does this answer your question? POI check cell is whether empty or not?

Are you using epplus open xml? if so, you can try open your excel file using Unarchiver on Mac, or some unzip tools on windows. you will see a folder "Book1/xl/worksheets". open the "sheet1.xml" using some pretty json formatter tool online. You will see all the Non-Null cells listed there. If a cell is not listed in that xml, then it will be null in csharp.

Hi @RahulSharma, many thanks for helping here. The problem is not locating what value the cell will be returned from the code itself. This code, in Net8 and using NPOI --var cellAA = sheet. GetRow(i). GetCell(j)-- will return a null or empty value as appropriate and I will handling. What I would be interested to know is how I can identify this difference from the excel itself. Many Thanks again.

Hi @rachel. No, I am using NPOI library.

OK. I haven't used NPOI before, but I managed to find nuget package code in Github: NPOI. see line38 public static CT_Cell Parse(XmlNode node, XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager). if XmL node is null, value will be null. so I think my previous comment still apply. you can unzip your excel into Xml files to find out whether a cell will be read as a null or  string.Empty.

If you are wondering why some cells are null, some cells are string.Empty, even if ISBLANK() returns TRUE. here is one possibility, you input something in a cell, then delete content. then that cell will be string.Empty, not null. but if you never touch that cell, then it will be null. Unfortunately, MS Excel code is not freely available online, so we can never be sure.
